# RSA finding the inverse of the public exponent

Tags: rsa

I have a very basic doubt in RSA key generation and its usage.

In RSA key generation you choose two large prime numbers of a very large order. Then you multiply them.(eq `p * q = N`)
Now, `Euler(N)=(p-1)(q-1)`. Now you find a number `0 < e < Euler(N)` such that e and Euler(N) are coprime. `{e.Euler(N)}` becomes your public key. Now you compute d(private key) such that `e * d =1 (mod(Euler(N)))`.
 Now suppose you encrypt something(m) with your the public key - `c=m^e(mod(N)).` 
And now while decrypting with the private key(d), you do `c^d(mod(N))`.
Now my doubt is that you found out the inverse of e in mod(Euler(N)), but when you are decrypting you are doing it in mod(N). How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem). Basically, you want decryption to "undo" encryption.  Since e⋅d = 1 mod φ(N) is equivalent to e⋅d = 1 + k⋅φ(N) for some integer k, you have:

c<sup>d</sup> mod N = (m<sup>e</sup>)<sup>d</sup> mod N = m<sup>(e⋅d)</sup> mod N = m<sup>(1 + k⋅φ(N))</sup> = (m<sup>1</sup>) ⋅ (m<sup>φ(N)</sup>)<sup>k</sup> mod N

by application of the following rules you learned in algebra:

1) a<sup>xy</sup> = (a<sup>x</sup>)<sup>y</sup> = (a<sup>y</sup>)<sup>x</sup>, and
2) a<sup>x+y</sup> = a<sup>x</sup> ⋅ a<sup>y</sup>

To finish this and simplify (m<sup>1</sup>) ⋅ (m<sup>φ(N)</sup>)<sup>k</sup> mod N, remember that a<sup>φ(N)</sup> = 1 mod N, so

(m<sup>φ(N)</sup>)<sup>k</sup> mod N = 1<sup>k</sup> = 1 mod N.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I still don't get the part where a^phi(N) = 1. How is it ensured that a(which is our message) and N are coprime. I did not quite understand your explanation for it.

Comment: @Ashwin: It is not ensured. It just incredibly unlikely to occur for the expected sizes of RSA moduli, so the possibility is ignored.

Comment: okay.. N=p*q where p and q are prime numbers. So, the only cse where a and N are not co prime is when a=p or a=q right? which is very unlikely.

Comment: @Ashwin: Correct, actually when a is any multiple of p or q.

Comment: I have another question. How is the message actually ancrypted. I am asking this because if you use a 2048 bit key, your data should not exceed 256 bytes. Why such a restriction or rather how is athere such a restriction?

Comment: @Ashwin: Since we using modular arithmetic, both m and m + k*N for any k encrypt to the same value. Upon decryption, how would you know which was the correct plaintext? To ensure unique decryption RSA has the restriction 0 <= m < N.

Comment: okay.. then how is the message encrypted. Like for example if the input string is "abcde" what is abcde converted into before feeding it to rsa algorithm. And where does it take the size of "abcde" into account.

Comment: The "message" is only a randomly chosen encryption key for another strong algorithm, such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard and then you proceed to encrypt the actual message with that.